# `where` equivalent in type declaration

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to declare an `associatedtype` that conforms to protocol with a specific property, namely `RawRepresentable where Self.RawValue == String`.

This is what I got so far.

```
protocol StatefulView: class {
  associatedtype StateType: RawRepresentable, Hashable
}
```

But it's not precise enough. I need a `where` clause, but *where* do I put it?

Comment: Swift currently doesn't support [arbitrary requirements in protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#arbitrary-requirements-in-protocols-), and I don't believe there's an easy workaround to achieve it either. Although depending on your use case, you may be able to use a wrapper type.

Comment: So much for protocol oriented programming for me... At least for the time being!

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird situation. Another thing you can't do with Swift (but can with Objective C, oddly enough) is to declare a variable with a class and a protocol, something like `UIView <ContentDisplay> *display`.